# find all strings between quotation marks

Tags: c#

I have a string:

**text abc="gsdfhdfhdfjdgfj" cde="1234 235" >hh**

I am trying to get the words that are found in quotation marks (there are more then two words in quotation marks..

so in this example, I have two get two strings:

```
gsdfhdfhdfjdgfj
1234 235
```

I know I can do it with `regular expressions`, but maybe there is another solution? maybe with `substring`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-Regex version looks something like this:

```
private static IList<string> betweenQuotes(string input)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    int leftQuote = input.IndexOf("\"");

    while (leftQuote > -1)
    {
        int rightQuote = input.IndexOf("\"", leftQuote + 1);
        if (rightQuote > -1 && rightQuote > leftQuote)
        {
            result.Add(input.Substring(leftQuote + 1, (rightQuote - (leftQuote + 1))));
        }
        leftQuote = input.IndexOf("\"", rightQuote + 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Results in a list containing your two examples.

Answer (score 3):

```
string str = "text abc=\"gsdfhdfhdfjdgfj\" cde=\"1234 235\" >hh";

var result = str.Split('"').Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 1).ToList();
```